# Unique drinks to make Halloween memorable?

Tags: pairing, drink, holidays

Are there any unique drinks out there to pair with Halloween in order to make it truly memorable?

We like having a Halloween party in an area with some so called haunted houses and where stories of Sasquatches abound. we have a grand old time with stories, movies and eats the whole week of *Hell Week* (the week leading up to Halloween).

For my part, I would like to bring the following eats to our evening soirees:

- My own variation of the [Croque Monsieur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croque-monsieur). The béchamel sauce that I make contains enough  *Keens Mustard* to make your eyes weep and your nose run. These are best served warm to hot, but can be eaten cold.
- [Mummy Dogs](http://www.southernliving.com/food/holidays-occasions/) or something resembling [Piggy Coffins](http://www.thegastrognome.com/2012/10/14/halloween-food-piggy-coffins/).
- **Green pasta** salad dish of sorts.
- [Stuffed Jack-O-Lanterns Bell Peppers](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/180596/stuffed-jack-o-lantern-bell-peppers/?internalSource=hn_carousel%2001_Stuffed%20Jack-O-Lantern%20Bell%20Peppers&referringId=17275&referringContentType=recipe%20hub&referringPosition=carousel%2001) which after my *Croque Monsieurs* are my favorite.

Comment: I suppose Bloody Marys are too obvious?

Comment: @EricShain I would not think so. Make a go of it!

Comment: In memoriam: Mickey Finn

Comment: I'll poke around more later but I think you wanted to ask about making Halloween "memorable".  Something that is easily and/or fondly remembered as opposed to memorial meaning a reminder of something that's passed, usually events or people.  I can edit things but I don't want to go over your head since it's your question.

Comment: @Sloloem You are so right. Thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to think of drinks with scary names. Specifically you could serve [Zombie Dust](https://www.3floyds.com/beer/zombie-dust/) from 3 Floyds Brewing which has the advantage of being a really [excellent beer](https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/26/64228/).

[image]

A Google search for "Halloween themed beer" will yield several articles with similarly scary named beers such as [here](https://www.craftbeer.com/craft-beer-muses/12-frighteningly-delicious-beers-halloween) and [here](https://learn.kegerator.com/scary-halloween-beers/).

Lastly, there is the [Pumpkin Ale](https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/style/72/) beer style.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try this  chillischnaps liquor: Kehlenschneider. It has an 80% ABV and is a real evil drink if taken in untamed quantities!

Kehlenschneider is of German origin and means **throat slicer** and some say it is the hottest liquor/liqueur in the world.

[image: Kehlenschneider]

[Kehlenschneider](http://www.kehlenschneider.de/index1.htm)

**Caution**: This is one hot drink and is made with extremely hot peppers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try some orange wine. Pumpkins and pumpkin colored foods and drinks are often associated with Halloween.

[Crushing: Orange Wines](http://blog.cookingchanneltv.com/2010/10/19/orange-wine-in-time-for-halloween/)

> “That’s right: red, pink and white have company,” exclaimed a recent newsletter from the Chelsea Wine Vault. Laden with cartoony images of a wine glass filled with bright orange liquid and a grape vine dangling bright orange grapes, the newsletter featured an infamous, under-the-radar vino known as orange wine.  Save all judgment! Unlike gimmicky green beer sold on St. Pat’s Day, orange wine has a legitimate backstory…
>
> The practice of making orange wines, despite its relative anonymity, spans centuries, dating all the way back to Eurasian wine production in Georgia (and we’re not talking the Peachtree State here). Much of the orange wine that is commercially distributed today comes from Italy (specifically its northeastern Friuli region), but other producers include France, Germany and California.

[image: Orange Wines -- A great get for your Halloween Party? Photograph by: Tom Censani]

**Orange Wines** -- A great get for your Halloween Party? Photograph by: Tom Censani